# Which database schema should I use?

Tags: 7, database

I want to create a custom voting module to learn how to write a module. The vote table will contain four fields (id, title, vote_up, vote_down).
Should I create a new table? If I create a new database table, how do I keep the relationship with the node being voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a voting module you should look into [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi), it's an API module that offers common functions and database storage for voting modules to use.

However, since this is a learning excercise, you might want to do it all yourself, in this case:

- Use [hook_schema()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_schema/6) to define your database schema (the example on the documentation page is pretty self-explanatory!)
- In Drupal 6 you need to manually specify which schema to install so implement [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_install/6) and [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_uninstall/6):

```
function mymodule_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('mymodule');
}

function mymodule_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema('mymodule');
}
```

An example of a hook_schema might look like this:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_schema()
 */
  function mymodule_schema() {
    $schema['mymodule_votes'] = array(
      'description' => 'Your schema',
      'fields' => array(
        'vid' => array(
          'description' => 'vote id',
          'type'        => 'serial',
          'unsigned'    => TRUE,
          'not null'    => TRUE,
        ),
        'nid' => array(
          'description' => 'node id',
          'type'        => 'int',
          'unsigned'    => TRUE,
          'not null'    => TRUE,
        ),
        'vote_up' => array(
          'description' => 'number of votes up',
          'type'        => 'int',
          'unsigned'    => TRUE,
          'not null'    => TRUE,
          'default'     => 0
        ),
        'vote_down' => array(
          'description' => 'number of votes down',
          'type'        => 'int',
          'unsigned'    => TRUE,
          'not null'    => TRUE,
          'default'     => 0
        ),
      ),
      'primary key'     => array('vid'),
      'indexes'         => array('node id' => array('nid'))
    );
    return $schema;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! i want to do it all myself. if i create three fields(ID, vote_up, vote_down), how to make a relationship with the node id?

Comment: i don't want to use voting api. in my module i only use.eg:$row['votes_up'] - $row['votes_down'];

Comment: I would create an extra (indexed) field in your schema for the node id :)

Comment: could you write down the  hook_schema() part on you answer, many thanks. i only want the vote module can vote up/down to the node article.

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

[Examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) has a [NodeAPI example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/nodeapi_example--nodeapi_example.module/group/nodeapi_example/7) that implements a five-star vote on nodes.

For a D7 version, you'd want to deal with entities instead, but it's a working example of how you might set up a schema for voting, based on your needs.